# junit test error - ClassCastException

Tags: java, junit

When trying to run a junit test I get the following error -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: business.Factory cannot be cast to services.itemservice.IItemsService
at business.ItemManager.get(ItemManager.java:56)
at business.ItemMgrTest.testGet(ItemMgrTest.java:49)
```

The specific test that is causing the problem is

```
@Test
public void testGet() {
        Assert.assertTrue(itemmgr.get(items));
}
```

The code it is testing is...

```
public boolean get(Items item)  { 

        boolean gotItems = false;       

        Factory factory = Factory.getInstance();

        @SuppressWarnings("static-access")
        IItemsService getItem = (IItemsService)factory.getInstance();

        try {
            getItem.getItems("pens", 15, "red", "gel");
            gotItems = true;
        } catch (ItemNotFoundException e) {
            // catch
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error - Item Not Found");
        }
        return gotItems;
    }
```

The test to store items, which is nearly identical, works just fine...

The factory class is..

```
public class Factory {

    private Factory() {}
    private static Factory Factory = new Factory();
    public static Factory getInstance() {return Factory;}




    public static IService getService(String serviceName) throws ServiceLoadException {
        try {
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(getImplName(serviceName));
            return (IService)c.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ServiceLoadException(serviceName + "not loaded");
        }
    }



    private static String getImplName (String serviceName) throws Exception {
        java.util.Properties props = new java.util.Properties();
            java.io.FileInputStream fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("config\\application.properties");
                props.load(fis);
                    fis.close();
                    return props.getProperty(serviceName);
}
}
```

Comment: What is method `Factory.getInstance()` like? It seems it return a `Factory` object but `IItemsService`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Factory.getInstance method returns a Factory object, and Factory is not IItemsService. Maybe you need to change the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
IItemsService getItem = (IItemsService)factory.getInstance();
```

to:

```
@SuppressWarnings("static-access")
IItemsService getItem = (IItemsService)factory.getService(serviceName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have called the wrong method. The method `Factory.getInstance()` returns an instance (which is singleton according to your implementation), hence it will throw a `ClassCastException` when you cast `Factory` to `IItemService`.

I don't see any method in your `Factory` that return `IItemService`. The only method makes sense here is `getService` which returns an `IService`. But it may throw `ClassCastException` if you try to cast `IService` to `IItemService` and the IItemService does not extend IService.